# Spreadsheet lookup by empty cell as a key

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, lookup, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I know how to lookup last non-empty value in a row using 
`=LOOKUP("X";$B2:$E2;$B1:$E1)`

But if I try to use an empty cell as a key, it causes an #N\A as a result.

How can I get "**5 Jan**" as a result in this example? I need to get date that matches up last empty cell in a row.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(2:2="", 1:1, )), 
 "where Col1 is not null limit 1", 0))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE (the last non-empty):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(1, MAX(IF((1:1<>"")*(2:2=""), COLUMN(1:1), )))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you!
But it shows first empty date and I need last one.

Comment: I have edited query with "order by Col1 desc". It is not quite the same as last column but as long as I have my columns sorted it works well.